# Where can i get OpenCV for python?

Tags: python, opencv

Where can i get OpenCV for python?What are the pre-requisites?? i tried to install opencv-python through synaptic package manager but Python says

> No module named CVtypes

Comment: I've been trying for months to get OpenCV to work with Python. And every time a new version comes out, I try again. I work with it with C++ or Microsoft C++/CLI/C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CVTypes is a third party implementation that essentially wraps python around objects written in C, the language that OpenCV is written in (along with C++). If you want to use that, you will have to download and install it separately, as it is not part of the standard repositories of Ubuntu's Synaptic package manager that I know of at this time (I assume you are on Ubuntu because you mentioned 'Synaptic', Ubuntu's package manager).

However, there is an official python interface for OpenCV that is included in the OpenCV SVN repository and build packages. When installing version 1.0 from the package manager in Ubuntu, the python modules will be installed in the following directory:

> /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/opencv

Ensure that is part of your PYTHONPATH environment variable and you should be able to import the modules as such:

```
from opencv.cv import *
from opencv.highgui import *
```

Answer (score 4):

OpenCV over time has accumulated numerous Python bindings, mostly due to the strange way arrays are represented in OpenCV (IMHO). Here is a short list:

- [PyOpenCV](http://code.google.com/p/pyopencv/)
- [Scikits Image](http://stefanv.github.com/scikits.image/api/scikits.image.opencv.html)
- [Ctypes OpenCV](http://code.google.com/p/ctypes-opencv/)
- [SWIG OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/SwigPythonInterface)

Choose which one you want to use and keep it consistent and upto date. I personally prefer the classic WillowGarage version[listed last] over its fancier cousins since it has most development and test muscle behind it.

Answer (score 2):

get it from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) unofficial binary packages.

by the way, they provide unofficial packages for many other projects

Answer (score 0):

Tried the official website? http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome

Comment: i found the link for opencv library at sourceforge,but does it include libraries for python?

Answer (score 0):

check your `openCV` version. Version 2 needs a simple

```
import cv
```

you may have a look at the `samples/python` folder.

Answer (score -1):

this webpage explains in great depth on the installation
http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/05/install-opencv-in-windows-for-python.html

after the installation try out the samples provided by opencv\samples\python2